# How can I exclude specific html pages in an AASA File for universal links?

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links, associated-domains

Is there a way to exclude specific html pages in AASA File? For example this is the URL which I do not want to open via App:

```
https://example.com/test.html?type=asdf&code=X12345&language=de-DE
```

but I want to open for example the following urls via app:

```
https://example.com/pathX/triggerApp.html?c=1234567890&l=de-DE

https://example.com/fwd/c/12345678
```

Does anyone have a clue how to achieve this. Or do I have to ask the backend guys to adapt the urls to be able to differentiate on app side?

Answer (score 0):

You can include only the ones you need by using the `paths` value.

As for excluding urls, Apple documentation does not tell much, but in this other question seems like you can just use something like:

`paths: ["NOT \some\excluded", "\some\other\included", ...]`

[exclude a url in universal links iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43276065/exclude-a-url-in-universal-links-ios)